# How to represent transitions of a NFA in Python?

Tags: python, state, transition, automata, nfa

I need to implement the following NFA:

[image]

I represent each state with functions, but I'm having trouble to get all possible paths given an input.

For example with an input "bb" I should have the next output:

```
Path 1: 1, 5, 1
Path 2: 1, 5, 3
Path 3: 1, 5, 7
Path 4: 1, 5, 9
```

I tried to represent the transitions with list of lists or a dictionary but I can't seem to find a way to get all the possible paths.

Comment: This might be a lot, but I actually wrote an oop implementation of NFA and DFA for a Lexer-Parser library. If you want to have a look at it: https://github.com/omelancon/ComPyl/blob/master/compyl/__lexer/finite_automaton.py

Answer (score 1):

You may implement in lot ways as matrix representation or adjacency list 
Here I have example that how you can represent your NFA

```
start_node = 1  # keep start nodes
final_states = [9]  # there may be multiple final states so keep them all in list

# Now you can construct a dictionary having key as transition and key as possible states can be reached
# Here key of tuple is (<current-state>, 'input symbol')  and corresponding value is of list containing all the possible states can be reached.
paths = {
(1, 'b') : [5],
(1, 'n') : [2, 4],
(2, 'b') : [3, 5],
(2, 'n') : [4, 6],
(3, 'b') : [5],
(3, 'n') : [2, 6],
}
```

To iterate over it you can find all states as in graph. If you consider it as a graph your problem is to find all the possible paths.

What you need to do is look for start state

- If entry of start state (start node) with input symbol exist in key then you need to explore all the nodes(list elements) otherwise break the loop and result will be the string is not accepted.

  > i.e. if input string is `'bb'` then you need to explore `[5]` because `(1, 'b')` exists
- until string ends you need to explore all the nodes explored from start state and the node explored from those nodes.

Refer [Python Graph Representation doc](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) for basic overview
Refer [this](https://www.python-course.eu/graphs_python.php) thread for more detail information